# Sorting algorthm: assembly

Tags: c, assembly, yasm

I am implementing a function for a bubblesort algorithm in assembly language (Linux, 64-bit, yasm). The function is called from within a C file where the array and the array size are passed through to assembly via rdi and rsi respectively.

```
  xor rax, rax
  xor rbx, rbx
  xor r14, r14                  ; r14 : int j = 0
  xor r15, r15                  ; r15 : boolean swapped
  inc r15                       ; swapped = true    (=> swapped = 1)

  while:  
    cmp r15, 1                  ; while (swapped)   (=> check if  swapped == 1)
    jne end_while   

    dec r15                     ; swapped = false   (=> swapped = 0)
    inc r14                     ; j++    
    mov rdx, rsi                ; rdx = size
    sub rdx, r14                ; size - j
    xor rcx, rcx                ; int i = 0

  for:
    cmp rcx, rdx                ; i < size - j
    je end_for

    mov rax, [rdi+rcx*4+4]      ; rax = rdi+rcx*4+4 => arr[i+1]
    mov rbx, [rdi+rcx*4]        ; rbx = rdi+rcx*4   => temp = arr[i]

    cmp rbx, rax                ; if(arr[i] > arr[i+1])
    jng done_if

    mov  [rdi+rcx*4], rax       ; arr[i] = arr[i+1]
    mov  [rdi+rcx*4+4], rbx     ; arr[i+1] = temp        
    inc r15                     ; swapped = true (=> swapped = 1)

    done_if:

    inc rcx                     ; ++i
    jmp for

  end_for:  
  end_while:
    ret
```

The array sorts integers only. I coded the bubblesort in Java and tested it there - it works fine. However, when I pass the array {9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1,0} via the C file the output is {8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,8,9}. I debugged with gdb but still can't see where the issue is. The for-loop construction works fine (rcx and rdx function correctly). It seems that there might be an issue with the way the array elements are accessed. 
Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: you debugged with gdb - so at what point did the array contents no longer make sense?

Comment: This seems like a bizarre thing to do - implement an incredibly inefficient algorithm in assembly code - are you just doing this for your own amusement, or as a homework assignment, or something like that ?

Comment: why not use avx since this is 64 bit and linux?

Comment: i think the best way to code things in asm is to code it in C first, then rely on compiler to translate it into asm, then optimize.

Comment: One problem I see is that you never resume the while loop, i.e. there is no jump to the 'while' label.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are using quadwords (64-bit integers) everywhere but your array is full of doublewords (32-bit integers).  In particular, the part where you used `mov rax, [rdi+rcx*4+4]` should be changed to `movl eax, [rdi+rcx*4+4]`, and the other `mov` instructions should similarly be changed to `movl`.